# Defining a global variable inside module in Drupal

Tags: drupal, global-variables

I am trying to save a global variable in my module and access it from another function. I don't want to store it in $_SESSION because I need this variable application wide. Following is the code what I am trying but it simply doesn't work.

```
  function popmeup_menu() {
    $items['example/feed'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example RSS feed',
     'page callback' => 'popmeup_page',
     'access arguments' => array('access content'),
     'type' => MENU_CALLBACK
    );
    return $items;
  }

    function popmeup_page() {
      print variable_get($xmlt, "");
    }

    function popmeup_comment_insert($comment) {
      variable_set($xmlt,"xmltoreturn");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To store a global variable, store it in `$GLOBALS` superglobal.

Or, perhaps, you can use a static value.

`$GLOBALS`: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

`static` variables: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: Actually, `popmeup_page()`, and `popmeup_comment_instert()` are called in two different page requests. This means that any global, or static variable is reset, and the value passed to those variables is not kept.

Answer (score 4):

If all you need is to have a place to store your variable WITHIN the same requests, for different functions to access, then have a look at [drupal_static](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_static/7). If you need to keep track of your variable across multiple requests, then the $_SESSION is the place to look.

Mārtiņš Briedis is right about static_variables, and drupal_static is just the formalised way of doing it.

Comment: This is the correct answer, as it considers when the value is required inside the same page request, or in different requests.

Answer (score 0):

`popmeup_comment_insert()`(an implementation of [hook_comment_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!comment!comment.api.php/function/hook_comment_insert/7)) is called in a different page request than `popmeup_page()`. As consequence of this, any static or global variable is automatically reset when the relative page request is done.

The only alternative you have is using Drupal variables, or a custom database table used from your module. I would discard Drupal variables, as they are loaded during Drupal bootstrap, even if their value is not requested to build the page content. In your case, as you need those values when outputting your page, I would rather use a custom database table.

As you are using `hook_comment_insert()` to populate it, you should consider that different users can insert a new comment at the same time, or before your page callback is invoked. Your code should need to consider that. If two different users create a new comment, which value should be saved in the database?